# Share users profiles across multiple SocialEngine setups

Tags: socialengine

Is it possible to share users profiles between two separate installations of Social Engine? I would like to have separate content (events, pages, classifieds ,groups etc.) for each installation and have common users for both sites (same domain, different folders).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the socialengine Socialengine single sign on plugin:

http://www.ipragmatech.com/socialengine-single-sign-on